# Subset data.frame to two sets of ranges for one variable

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset a dataset and take out a center range.

The data goes from 0 to 150 but I would like to subset and only keep data from 0-60 and 90-150.

How can I do that?

Comment: What kind of dataset do you have? `data.frame`, `list`, `vector`? In R, data index starts in 1, in python in 0. Put some example code or a part of your data.

Comment: My data is in a data.frame. The variable is dayssince (days since an intervention).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data.frame is named as `df`:

```
df[df$dayssince %in% c(0:60,90:150),]
```

Remember that selection or subset can takes into account a boolean vector. That is what I take in account here

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!